# Handling event listeners on multiple pages

Tags: javascript

I've written a javascript file which has some event listeners in for things like tabs, accordions and so on. However these aren't present in every single page so it's looking for elements that don't exist and throws the entire js out of wack.

I know I could get around it by using multiple if statements, but it doesn't sound like it would be correct.

```
// Accordion
const accordions = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion li');

accordions.forEach(accordion =>{
    accordion.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        accordion.classList.toggle('open');
    })
});

// Inline toggle
const inlineToggle = document.getElementById('inline-toggle');

inlineToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
    inlineToggle.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('active');
});

const inlineToggleOptions = document.querySelectorAll('.inline-toggle-options button');
inlineToggleOptions.forEach(option => {
    option.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        // Prevent default
        e.preventDefault();
        // Update sentence text
        inlineToggle.innerHTML = option.dataset.payType;
        // Remove selected class from options
        inlineToggleOptions.forEach(option => {
            option.classList.remove('selected');
        });
        // Add selected class to chosen option
        option.classList.add('selected');
        // Close dialog
        inlineToggle.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('active');
    })
});

// Cover bubbles

// Create the slidepanel
const placeholder = document.getElementById('slidepanel');

// Find all buttons
const button = document.querySelectorAll('.trigger-aside');

button.forEach((button => {

    // Listen for clicks on buttons
    button.addEventListener('click',(e) => {

        // Prevent default
        e.preventDefault();

        // Get the target
        const target = button.dataset.target;
        console.log(target);

        // Call the API
        fetch(`http://****.****.uk/****/****/****/${target}`)
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then(function(res) {

                // Load HTML into slider panel
                placeholder.innerHTML = res.object.content;

                // Stop body overflow
                document.body.classList.add('overflow-hidden');

                // Create overlay and append
                const overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');
                overlay.classList.add('active');
                document.body.appendChild(overlay);

                // Show the panel
                placeholder.classList.add('active');
                document.body.appendChild(placeholder);

                // Listen for close
                overlay.addEventListener('click', (e) =>{
                    // Close requested
                    document.body.classList.remove('overflow-hidden');
                    placeholder.classList.remove('active');
                    overlay.classList.remove('active');
                });

            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                // Log error
                console.log(err);
            });

    })
}));
```

How do other people generally get around this issue? Any guidance appreciated!!

Comment: Break the file up into multiple files and only load the scripts that are needed per page.

Comment: @StevenB. Thanks - is there not a better way than that though as I want to ultimately compile and minify into one script to be efficient..?

Comment: Using `if` is not unusual. Perhaps you can group them together into page specific functions also

Comment: @Stephanie I'd say loading more code than necessary at a single time is inefficient, right?  But for simplicity an easy way around writing a bunch of conditionals is to do null checks on the elements as such `inlineToggle && inlineToggle.addEventListener(...)` so the event is only added if the `inlineToggle` exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Event Delegation Pattern

If you have these UI elements grouped under a parent element in common across all pages(like a div wrapper), you could try making use of the [Event Delegation pattern](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/). Essentially, you can assign a click event to that parent element and make use of a function to only take action if the desired element is returned - i.e. your buttons. It would go something like...

```
const parent = document.querySelector('div.wrapper'); //Change selector to suit a common parent
const buttons = [...document.querySelectorAll('.inline-toggle-options button')]; // convert to array to make it easier to work with
const elementsToChange = document.querySelectorAll('.elements .to .change');

parent.addEventListener('click', toggleOptions);

function getEventTarget(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  return e.target || e.srcElement; // For IE compatibility
}

function toggleOptions {
  let target = getEventTarget(e);
  if(buttons.includes(target)) {
    // Trigger options on UI elements if any of the buttons are among the clicked elements
    // Target refers to the buttons in particular, not the UI elements you want to change
  }
}
```

Whichever way you want to refactor the code to take action on specific elements is up to you. You can group buttons by specific functionality into distinct arrays. If you had 2 or 3 arrays, you'd only need to write 2 or 3 options from a conditional statement.

For this purpose, you'll also save memory with this pattern since you're only assigning one event handler and letting child events on child elements [bubble up](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing) to be taken care of by that single handler. Also, you shouldn't run into errors since the initial event handler is assigned to a parent element that's common across all pages.

#### Some Caveats

From the guide linked above:

> Not all events bubble. The blur, focus, load and unload events don’t
>   bubble like other events. The blur and focus events can actually be
>   accessed using the capturing phase (in browsers other than IE) instead
>   of the bubbling phase but that’s a story for another day.
>
> You need caution when managing some mouse events. If your code is
>   handling the mousemove event you are in serious risk of creating a
>   performance bottleneck because the mousemove event is triggered so
>   often. The mouseout event has a quirky behaviour that is difficult to
>   manage with event delegation.

Answer (score 1):

I'd generally advise to think first about code organisation and second about efficiency.  I agree with [StevenB.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5508690/steven-b)'s suggestion and [Luke Tubby](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11251449/luke-tubby)'s answer, to make the best of your current situation with a minimum of effort.

For more elaborate solutions, I would suggest to familiarise with build / packaging tools (e.g. [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) ), that offer you ways to structure your code (and assets) in files and directories of your choice, and create page specific minified packages.
Another (completely different and independent) approach to the problem (of improving efficiency and code organisation) would be to build a [single page application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application)...